# Carregar layout com PreferenceFragment em um DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawer-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um app que utiliza `DrawerLayout`. A abertura de cada item do menu é realizada conforme o código abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    ...

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Abre o primeiro item
                break;
            case 1:
                //Abre o segundo item
                break;
            case 2:
                //Abre o terceiro item
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ConfiguracoesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_configuracoes);
                break;
            case 4:
                title = getString(R.string.title_desconectar);
                startActivity(new Intent(this, InicialActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Cada item do menu é uma classe que estende de `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. O arquivo ConfiguracoesFragment também estende da mesma classe. Para utilizar `PreferenceFragment` devo estender a partir de `android.app.Fragment`, ou seja, não é possível fazer a substituição em `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)` pois `PreferenceFragment` não estende da mesma classe base.

**Como carregar uma classe que estende PreferenceFragment em um DrawerLayout?**

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de usar um `Fragment` da `support library` para exibir `Preferences`.

## Usando o novo `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

Usando o `PreferenceFragmentCompat` da `preference-v7` é bem simples.

Só que isso traz um pequeno problema, que dependendo do cenário é impraticável.

Você precisa importar a biblioteca `preference-v7`, colocando a declaração da dependência em seu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.1'
```

Um exemplo de uso:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Um pequeno detalhe que não está documentado, mas é preciso definir um atributo no seu tema:

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set

Só que isso implica em algumas coisas:

O `preference-v7` depende de outras três bibliotecas:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
```

Se você já utiliza essas bibliotecas, sem problemas. Caso contrário precisa avaliar essas mudanças.

Uma vantagem é que todos os componentes vão estar com os estilos e design do Material Design, que o `AppCompat` traz.

Isso porque ao usar a versão 23, você é obrigado a alterar seu `compileSdkVersion` e seu `targetSdkVersion` para 23. E ai começam alguns problemas.

Para não estender muito, ao dar suporte a versão 23, você precisa tomar muito cuidado com o novo [modelo de permissões](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) que gera uma forma diferente de estruturar certos fluxos de seu app.

## Usando um port do `PreferenceFragment`

Como uma alternativa, existe a biblioteca [`android-support-v4-preferencefragment`](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) que adiciona uma camada de compatibilidade.

Ela não é uma versão oficial do AOSP, mas se a primeira solução não for possível, não tem jeito, o que resta é usar esse port.

> Uma recomendação que eu dou é tentar evitar ao máximo usá-la, porque ela se baseia muito em aspectos da API interna de `Preferences`, usando bastante `Reflection` para realizar grande parte do trabalho. Isso é ruim porque se algo mudar numa próxima versão, você vai acabar descobrindo em tempo de execução.

A forma de uso é a mesma. Em vez de seu `Fragment` herdar de `PreferenceFragmentCompat` (no primeiro caso), ele vai herdar de `android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment`. E o resto continua igual.

Em relação primeiro, os componentes dessa biblioteca não vão estar com o estilo do Material Design que a `AppCompat` traz para todas as versões depois da 7.

Comment: Walkin, o PreferenceFragmentCompat me dá suporte ao actionbar?

Comment: Com relação as libs com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1,
com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 e 
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1, já as utilizo.

Comment: Infelizmente não diretamente, e acredito que não faça sentido isso também*. O `ActionBar` pertence a `AppCompatActivity`, sendo mais usada em termos do `Toolbar`. Logo você precisa delegar a responsabilidade de manipular para a sua `Activity`, mas nada lhe impede de acessar diretamente usando o método `getActivity` da classe `Fragment`.

Comment: Se já utiliza essas libs, perfeito :D

Comment: Acho que vou precisar criar uma outra pergunta. Mas enfim, como você faz para apresentar o título do toolbar e o botão "home" para voltar para a tela anterior? Você utiliza PreferenceFragmentCompat ou usa outra abordagem?

Comment: Perdão, estou me precipitando. Já tenho o toolbar, pois este fragmento é carregado pelo Drawerlayout. Vou testar sua solução.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade ainda não usei esse `preference-v7`, mas parece bem simples (as vezes tem algumas pegadinhas escondidas hehe). Mas sim, é uma outra pergunta. E acho que pra fazer a mudança de "Menu Drawer" pra "Arrow" recomendo usar a interface `OnBackStackChangedListener` que vai tornar seu código muito mais desacoplado.

Comment: @Walkin, está ocorrendo o erro `Must specify preferenceTheme in theme`. Como deve ser declado o tema?

Comment: Na minha resposta tem como resolver esse problema :)